# MySQL query to perform subtract between two tables for a single column by unique matching IDs

Tags: mysql

I want SQL query for following case:

I have 2 tables and I want to perform subtraction between their matching values of ID

Table-1 : invoice_master

```
ID              amount      status      type
--------------------------------------------
inv_id_1        150.00      Open        Invoice
inv_id_2        300.00      Open        Invoice
inv_id_3        500.00      Open        Invoice
inv_id_4        400.00      Open        Invoice
```

Table-2 : payment_master

```
ID          ref_invoice_ID    amount         status
-------------------------------------------------------
pmt_id_1          inv_id_1       100.00      Collected
pmt_id_2          inv_id_2       150.00      Confirmed
pmt_id_3          inv_id_3       330.00      Initiated
pmt_id_4          inv_id_4       400.00      Initiated
```

Expected RESULT  is following:

```
ID             sub_amt   |  Not table but explanation of calculation
-------------------------|--------------------------------------------
inv_id_1         50.00   | (150.00 - 50.00) amount of `inv_id_1` - Payment of `inv_id_1` in payment_master 
inv_id_2        150.00   | (300.00 - 150.00)
inv_id_3        170.00   | (500.00 - 330.00)
inv_id_3          0.00   | (400.00 - 400.00)
```

Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
 an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
 then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
 [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/),
 how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: How is this different from your previous question..

Comment: Hi, this question is different than previous one definitely.

Comment: @Akina how do  you see this similar? I got your solution on fiddle so I got halfway there and I thought of putting another possible solution in different question.

Comment: Does `invoice_master.ID` is defined as unique (maybe primary key) whereas `payment_master.ref_invoice_ID` is NOT unique?

Comment: yes you assumed right. invoice_master.ID is Primary_Key and payment_master.ref_invoice_ID is not unique. It can repeat in future.